# CKEditor image dialog is failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor

I worked with CKEditor on my .Net Mvc4 project. On localhost all works well, but after publishing project to server is not initialising:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'dir' of undefined"
```

I fixed this by adding code line before editor initialization:

CKEDITOR.basePath = '//some url/ckeditor/'

After that, the ckeditor is working but refusing  to open image upload dialog:

error in ckeditor plugins image.js

```
Uncaught Error: [CKEDITOR.dialog.openDialog] Dialog "image" failed when loading definition.
```

There is no any changes in my ckeditor folder. The version is: 4.4.5

Any solutions please?

Answer (score 2):

Check the "Network" tab in your browser for HTTP 404 errors. It looks like the file that contains Image Dialog definition is not available. Either it is not present (e.g. has been accidentally removed) or you have some weird url rewrite issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your `CKEDITOR.basePath` plugins folder image plugin is in there, if not then add it and wala working like a charm ! hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue

You are getting the error from only including the `ckeditor.js` (or `ckeditor4.js` since 4.13) file on server, with this error becoming raised when CKE attempts to load other features such as plugins and languages but cannot find these files in the basepath folder. You can confirm this from the network tab in browser devtools, as CKE attempts to load features, then cannot find them.

#### Option 1: Link to a CDN Bundle

CKE offers 3 primary bundles (basic, standard, full) which offer a choice between features and page load. [More info here.](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/)

#### Option 2: Include Necessary Files

Make the extra files available on your server.
Here's a gulp task which bundles everything from the ckeditor node module folder (excluding the sample).

```
gulp.task("copy-ckeditor", function () {
    // Check and copy languages in config.ckEditorLanguages
    var isIncluded = function(path) {
        var found = false,
            lang = path.split('lang')[1];

        if (lang) {
            for (var i in config.ckEditorLanguages) {
                if (lang.indexOf(config.ckEditorLanguages[i]) != -1) {
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return found;
    },
    copyFile = function(stream) {
        stream.pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildPath.js + "lib/ckeditor"));
    };

    return gulp.src([
            "node_modules/ckeditor/**/*.*",
            "!node_modules/ckeditor/samples",
            "!node_modules/ckeditor/samples/**/*"
        ])
        .pipe(foreach(function(stream, file){
            if (file.path.indexOf("lang") != -1) {
                if (isIncluded(file.path)) {
                    copyFile(stream);
                }
            } else {
                copyFile(stream);
            }
            return stream;
        }));
});
```

#### Option 3: Build and Host Your Own Custom Bundle

If you want to use a single file load, you can use the [CKE4 Builder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder) allowing you to customise built-in plugins.